# Print specific information of a json in Angular

Tags: node.js, json, angular, xmlhttprequest

How can i acces to products in this case? I want to show that infomation in a ngFor="let

App.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Bazaar';
  url = 'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar';
  //
  items = [];

  constructor(private json: JsonService) {
    this.json.getJson(this.url).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);

      for(let key in res)
      if(res.hasOwnProperty(key))
        this.items.push(res[key]);
    })
  }
```

App.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</div>
```

This is the Json Structure:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "lastUpdated": 1588676089955,
  "products": {
    "INK_SACK:3": {
      "product_id": "INK_SACK:3",
      "sell_summary": [
        {
          "amount": 5643,
          "pricePerUnit": 5.2,
          "orders": 1
        },
      ],
      "buy_summary": [
        {
          "amount": 63182,
          "pricePerUnit": 6.6,
          "orders": 2
        },
       ],
```

json.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JsonService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getJson(url: string){
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

I already tried item.products in the HTML and got nothing

Comment: use this to format your json https://jsonformatter.org/ and show a small example of your json mayebe one object, as this image is not readable

Comment: You have to show what you have been already trying. We can not understand why it doesn't work for you without seeing the code you have tried to use.

Comment: This is all the code, no more. I can show the information in console.log but no print in screen

Comment: 'I already tried item.products in the HTML and got nothing' - show us the HTML code.

Comment: <div *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.products}}</div>

Answer (score 0):

`item.products` is a json object and you can not bind an Object into the DOM.
If you want to present the object as a string - use [JSON.stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">{{JSON.stringify(item.products)}}</div>
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'stringify' of undefined. I'm going to look into stringify